# Send other data types in winsock2

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, winsock2

The send function in winsock2 accepts only char pointers.
How do I send integers or objects through it too?

Answer (score 5):

`const char *buf` which you need to pass to `send()` function as an argument is just a pointer to array of bytes. You need to convert integers to bytes:

```
const int MAX_BUF_SIZE = 1024;
int int_data = 4;
const char *str_data = "test";

char *buf = (char*) malloc(MAX_BUF_SIZE);
char *p = buf;

memcpy(&int_data, p, sizeof(int_data));
p += sizeof(int_data);

strcpy(p, str_data);
p += strlen(str_data) + 1;

send(sock, buf, p - buf, 0);

free(buf);
```

and reading code:

```
const int MAX_BUF_SIZE = 1024;
int int_data = 0;
const char *str_data = NULL;

char *buf = (char*) malloc(MAX_BUF_SIZE);
char *p = buf;

recv(sock, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE, 0);

memcpy(p, &int_data, sizeof(int_data));
p += sizeof(int_data);

str_data = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
strcpy(str_data, p);
p += strlen(p) + 1;

free(buf);
```

and complex objects needs to be [serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488330) to stream of bytes.

Note 1: The code sample is valid iff both server and client use the same platforms (x32 / x64 / ...) that means `int` has the same amount of bytes and byte order is the same.

Note 2: Writing code should check that there is no buffer (`MAX_BUF_SIZE`) overflow on each step.

Comment: for an integer should I use reinterpret_cast<char*>(i)?

Comment: "(that is easy)" - for those who know how to. If you have to ask this question, you're not going to find `htons` and `htonl()`. (@Pilpel: "hton" stands for "Host TO Network"; it changes the order of bytes to match that of TCP/IP. On receive, you'd use a "ntoh" function. Both exist in 's' (short, 16 bits) and 'l' (long, 32 bits) version.

Comment: How does this answer my question? the ntoh functions don't take char pointers and make them integers

Comment: @Pilpel: Not directly. It's the step you need to do before `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&result_of_htonl)`

Comment: I see. So the "host" word in hton could be both client and server code, right?

Comment: @Pilpel: I don't understand, why we need to swap the bytes before putting them to the buffer and then do a reverse operation. I would use `memcpy` to copy bytes (with assumption that `int` = 4 bytes on server and client platform and both platforms are e.g. x86).

Comment: I'm confused.
Could you post some lines of code to clear things up?

Comment: @Pilpel: I've added the sample. Sorry, it is not tested, but I hope you can catch the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the value into a variable and then type-cast the variable to `char*`.  The `send()` and `recv()` functions operate on binary data, despite taking `char*` parameters.

Sending:

```
int int_data = 4;
send(sock, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);
```

Reading:

```
int int_data;
recv(sock, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the easiest way is to print the integer or object to a string, and send that string. Textual representations are more portable, and also easier to debug.

`std::stringstream` may be a useful class both to create the string and parse it on the other end.

Comment: This serialization is ineffective. As long as you don't need a crossplatform portability you can use a memcpy semantik. Take the address of the object and its size and pass address and size to the winsock functions. You will need a cast here. When your data contain pointers to other objects you can't use the memcpy style. In that case you need serialization.

Comment: Ineffective? You even admit it's cross-platform, so it must certainly work.

Comment: So assuming I have an object with two data members, x and y, when x = 10 and y = 20.
Do you recommend me to send it as plain text like this: "10|20"?