# Serializing a c++ class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to serialize in c++ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/how-to-serialize-in-c)

I have a class

```
    Class Person
    {
      int age;
      char *name;

      char* Serialize()
      {
        //Need to convert age and name to char* eg:21Jeeva
      }
      void DeSerialize(char *data)
      {
        //Need to populate age and name from the data
      }
    };
```

In C# we can use MemoryStream,BinrayWriter/BinaryReader to achieve this. In c++ somewhere i found we can use iostream to achieve it. But couldnt able to get a proper example of it.

The purpose of the code is after calling serialize i am going to send the data over socket and in receiving end ill call DeSerialize to populate the members back.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [Boost.Serialization](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). If you only need a simple text-serialization based on iostreams, you probably want to overload the stream extraction operators. For serialization this could look like this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const Person & person) {
    stream << person.age << " " << person.name;
    return stream;
}
```

You have to make this function a friend of `Person` for this to work.

For deserialization, you would use this:

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & stream, Person & person) {
    stream >> person.age >> person.name;
    return stream;
}
```

Using these, you can do the following:

```
Person fred;
fred.name = "Fred";
fred.age = 24;

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << fred << std::endl;

Person fred_copy;
buffer >> fred;
```

You can find a small working example [here](http://ideone.com/boBt3).

Overloading these operators has the advantage that you can for instance use `std::copy` with an `std::ostream_iterator` to serialize an entire collection of Persons in one statement.

Comment: will this take care of ENDIAN formats?

Comment: @Jeeva: This serializes to text, so endianess will not be a problem.

Comment: Serialziation to text will not help. Since if the value is 100 i need to send it as 3 bytes but rather i want to send it as a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following wrapper to convert any datatype to character stream:

```
template<class TYPE>
string ToChar (const TYPE& value)
{
  stringstream ss;
  ss << value;
  return ss.str();
}
```

You can use the `string` object the way you want; like convert into char stream using `c_str()` or copy into array and so on.