# How to serialize a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to serialize in c++ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/how-to-serialize-in-c)

I have created a structure and I populated a vector with it. I would like to send this vector across the network using a socket, so I need to serialize it. But I don't know how to do. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Boost.serialization, Google protocol buffers, or do it by hand.