# For-loop vs assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy, bit-manipulation

Is direct assignment (*i.e.* `=`) the same as casting something to `char*` and then using a `for` loop to copy it byte after byte?<sup>*</sup>
I want to know if there's an advantage of one method over the other.

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Test;

void* Buffer = malloc(1024);


// Casting and byte copying
for (int i=0; i != 8; i++)
{
    ((char*)Buffer)[i] = ((char*)Test)[i];
}

// Assignment
((A*)Buffer)[0] = Test;
```

---

<sup>* all types are bitwise copyable.</sup>

EDIT:
based on answers, is memcopy the same as '='

Comment: Why not use memcpy?

Comment: Theres so many ifs, maybes, and somtimeses... just use the = operator.  Yes, it does a bitwise copy _in your case_, but what if the struct was not 8 bytes?/

Answer (score 10):

This is basically what `memcpy` does, and is valid for [POD types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) (assuming `sizeof(Test)` really is 8).  However, `memcpy` will almost certainly be faster, because the compiler will have special optimised assembler routines.

You'll invoke **undefined behaviour** if you try this (or `memcpy`) with a non-POD type.  So in general, you should use `std::copy` or just use assignment.

You should also avoid `malloc` in C++, because it's not type-safe; use `new`, or [placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new) if you have to.

Comment: everyting going into the buffer is either POD or an array of POD.

Comment: @user1204406: Then the manual copying is safe.  But it's also pointless, probably slower, and harder to read/maintain than a simple `=`.

Comment: theres a time when i need to spread one object over 2 buffers. so manual copying is nessacary. but sometimes it only goes into one buffer so '=' works there. should i make a special case for if i can fit it or just stick with the for loop to be consistant?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "However, `memcpy` will almost certainly be faster"---I'd expect just the opposite. `memcpy` is generic; it has to handle all possible situations.  If you write the loop (or use `std::copy`), the compiler can see the exact conditions, and optimize accordingly.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm comparing `memcpy` to the manual for loop.  My understanding is that most compilers have a `memcpy` intrinsic, although this is not something I've ever dug into.

Comment: @JamesKanze: all semi-decent compilers have a `memcpy` intrinsic and are able to turn a copy loop into `memcpy` and vice-versa.

Comment: @user1204406: I would still be tempted to use `memcpy` rather than a manual loop.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth A lot of C compilers might have a `memcpy` intrinsic, but C++ is a different kettle of fish.  The usual technique for implementing the intrinsic (a special macro) isn't legal in C++, and because the function is so dangerous, it's rarely used in C++, so why should a compiler vendor invest the effort to develop a new technique?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I would never use `memcpy` in C++, because it rarely works---very, very few data types are POD.  And there's `std::copy`, which does the job correctly.  (I wouldn't hand write such a loop either.)

Comment: @user1204406 If you're marshalling for transmission, none of the solutions mentioned so far work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not C++. This is ugly C. You're manually allocating a block of memory the size of 1024 bytes, capturing its address in a naked pointer. Also, in the code sample, you never free any of it, leaking a MB of memory. This is considered an extremely bad practice when it comes to C++.

C++ is not C with classes, it's a beautiful language that can only express itself by using it in combination with the standard library and adhering to better design patterns which come naturally with OO programming, especially with the notions of RAII, general encapsulation which can result in better memory management. Even `new` is evaded when unnecessary, let alone `malloc`.

```
for (int i=0; i != 8; i++)
```

Also, you're making dangerous assumptions here which can lead to undefined behavior.

```
((char*)Buffer)[i] = ((char*)Test)[i];
```

I am not even going to comment on this. Holy... Not only it's bad, it doesn't work. You're trying to force an instance of `struct` `A` lying on the stack, a regular "object"/var, into a `char*`. You're missing the `&Test`.

**Use memcpy if you're taking this path**, but please consider improving on your C++ approach. memcpy takes three arguments, a destination, a source and the size in bytes. Make sure the two match up and you'll get a quick per-byte copy.

Comment: :cant send pointers over TCP. PART of this is loading classes w/pointers into a buffer so it can be bitwise copyied. so i need a block of memory that can hold the class data and the arrays inside(dynamicaly allocated). And no, im not going to free something that will be reused, thats less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Direct assignment, using the `=` operator, is definitely *not* the same
as a `for` loop copying the bytes.  The `=` operator respects the type,
and what it does will depend on the type.  And copying byte by byte is
undefined behavior in most cases.  In your particular case, I would
expect that the compiler generate something equivalent to treating the
data as an unsigned long long, and copying that, with just one or two
machine instructions.  But that's only because of the particularities of
the type you defined.  In general, give the compiler as much information
as you can, and trust it; it will usually do a better job that you can.

Comment: read Oli's answer and comments, there are two buffers so i need to break the struct into smaller types.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to OP's question but instead, it is an answer to what I think he is trying to achieve.

Writing formatted data to a transferable format is [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and in C++, there are several ways to do this.  There are several things to consider: should the format be ascii, xml, binary and in case of binary, should it be crossplatform (endianess, alignment).  In any case, the naive way of copying structs to a byte buffer is almost never desirable.

You can consider following options:

- when it may be in ascii format, the most straightforward way is to use iostreams
- [boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization)
- external libraries (fair enough: boost is also one): poco, google buffer protocol, ...
- rolling your own (based on converting primitives)

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/how-to-serialize-in-c)

Comment: Hit the nail on the head. I would like write it myself though so I learn more.

Comment: Doing it myself, is it worth making a special case to use "="?

Comment: No, if you want to overload an operator, use operator<< to stream to your buffering stream, so it is similar to streaming to std::cout

Comment: No I'm not making a class. I want to copy a POD into a buffer. Should I Make a special case to use = if the POD can fit into one buffer.