# How to store different classes in one Variable?

Tags: c++, conceptual

I have a little conceptual problem. I have different classes representing the geometric data of an edge depending what type of edge it is. For Example the class for a straight line and a circle:

```
class Line{
private: 
    double[3] startPoint;
    double[3] endPoint;
public:
    //getter and setter and some other functions such as equals

}

class Circle{
private: 
    double[3] center;
    double[3] planeNormal;
    double    radius;
public:
    //getter and setter and some other functions such as equals   
}
```

Now I need a class `Edge` which stores the type of the edge and the fitting geometric data.
In the end the Edge has to be stored in a `std::vector<Edge> edges;` The Problem is that I do not know the type before runtime, because I am analysing the boundary representation of CAD parts which can have various types of edges.

```
class Edge{
private:
    EdgeType type;
    GeometricData data;
public:
    //...
}
```

So how should I design my `class Edge` and espacially `GeometricData` which has to store either a `Line`-object, a `Circle`-object or another geometric object, so that I can go back from `GeometricData` to `Line`, `Circle` or whatever geometric class it may be.

- I tried polymorphism with `GeometricData` as base class, but the derived
  classes are too different, since things like B-Splines are also
  included.
- I also tried `GeometricData` as `void*` and a template-approach
  for the set- and get-methode, but with that I have problems
  storing the data and not only the pointer, because of the lifetime
  of the objects (I have to analyse the BRep recursivly).

I would also appreciate suggestions that may change the whole concept of the geometric representations, as long as I can access the type-fitting data such as `startPoint` of a straight line or `radius` of a circle using the `edges`-vector.

EDIT:
Thanks for the fast responses. I decided to use suszterpatt suggestion including some of my templates and changing my `std::vector<Edge>` to `std::vector<shared_ptr<Edge>>` as TAS mentioned. Now it looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum EdgeType{
    LINE = 100,
    CIRCLE
};

//Basis
class GeometricData {
private:
public:
    virtual string toXMLString() = 0;
};

class Line : public GeometricData{
//less code just for illustration
private:
    double d1;
public:
    double getD1() { return d1; }    
    void setD1(double d1) { this->d1 = d1;}
    virtual string toXMLString() {
        stringstream s;
        s << "d1=\"" << d1 <<"\"";
        return s.str();
    }
};

class Circle : public GeometricData{
private:
    double d2;
public:
    double getD2() { return d2; }
    void setD2(double d2) { this->d2 = d2;}
    virtual string toXMLString() {
        stringstream s;
        s << "d2=\"" << d2<<"\"";
        return s.str();
    }
};

class Edge{
private:
    EdgeType t;
    GeometricData* d;
public:
    Edge () { d = 0;}
    ~Edge () {if (d) {delete d; d=0;}}
    template <typename T> int   setGeomData (T data) {
        static_assert(
            is_same<T,Line*>::value || 
            is_same<T,Circle*>::value,
            "EdgeGeometryType is not supported");


        GeometricData* buffer = data;
            //set type corresponding to thethis->data given= data

            if(is_same<T,Line*>::value){
                this->t = LINE;
                Line* lb = dynamic_cast<Line*>(buffer);
                Line* l = new Line(*lb);
                this->d = l;
            }else if (is_same<T,Circle*>::value){
                this->t = CIRCLE;
                Circle* cb = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(buffer);
                Circle* c = new Circle(*cb);
                this->d = c;
            }else{// this case should not occure because of the static_assert
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;

    };
    template <typename T> T getGeomData () {
        static_assert(
            is_same<T,Line*>::value || 
            is_same<T,Circle*>::value, 
            "EdgeGeometryType is not supported");

        if ((this->t == LINE        && is_same<T,Line*>::value) || 
            (this->t == CIRCLE      && is_same<T,Circle*>::value))
        {
            return dynamic_cast<T>(this->d);
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    };
    EdgeType getType(){ return t; }
    //void setType(EdgeType t) { this->t = t; } not needed
    GeometricData* getData(){return d;}
};

class Model {
private:
    vector <shared_ptr<Edge>> edges;
public:
    Model(){}
    vector <shared_ptr<Edge>> getEdges(){ return edges; }
    void addEdge (Edge* e) {edges.push_back(shared_ptr<Edge>(e));}
    shared_ptr<Edge> getEdge(int i ){ return edges.at(i); }
};

// Functions
void foo2 (Edge* e){
    Line* l = new Line; 
    l->setD1(0.1);
    e->setGeomData<Line*>(l);
    //e->setType(LINE);   not needed
    delete l;
}
void foo1 (Edge* e){
    Circle c;
    c.setD2(0.2);
    e->setGeomData<Circle*>(&c);
    //e->setType(CIRCLE);  not needed
}
void foo (Model* mdl){
    Edge* e1 = new Edge;
    Edge* e2 = new Edge;
    foo1(e1);
    foo2(e2);
    mdl->addEdge(e1);
    mdl->addEdge(e2);
}   
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Model mdl;
    int i;
    foo(&mdl);
    cout << "Edge 1: " << mdl.getEdge(0)->getData()->toXMLString() << endl;
    cout << "Edge 2: " << mdl.getEdge(1)->getData()->toXMLString() << endl;
    for (i = 0; i<2; i++){
        switch (mdl.getEdge(i)->getType()){
            case LINE: {
                Line* ld = (mdl.getEdge(i)->getGeomData<Line*>());
                cout << "Line (templated get): " << ld->getD1() << endl;
            }break;
            case CIRCLE:{
                Circle* cr = (mdl.getEdge(i)->getGeomData<Circle*>());
                cout << "Circle (templated get): "<< cr->getD2() << endl;
            }break;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I tried polymorphism, but the derived classes are too different". Perhaps your base class was too specific? This sounds like a textbook case where polymophism could save the day: how are various shapes too different?

Comment: Hi suszterpatt,
I am relativly new to the concept of polymorphism. Maybe I don't understand it correctly. I thought that if I want to cast from basis to derived and back I need a virtual method for every methode of the derived classes in the basis class and each virtual method has to be implemented in each derived class. 
Please correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't this mean my class `Line` needs a `getRadius()`, because this has to be a virtual method of my basis `GeometricData`, since `Circle` needs this method?

Comment: Not all methods of a polymorphic class need to be virtual. The way it goes is, in the base class you define the common methods to be shared among all subclasses, and then in the subclasses, you override the base methods and define whatever additional methods are necessary for that particular subclass. The question is, does your `Edge` class need to know the exact type of the data it is operating on? E.g. must it know a circle's radius, or would a generic `getArea()` method in `GeometricData` suffice and `Circle` could ovverride that method and use its own radius?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. 
The Basis must exactly know what is stored, because the whole BRep will be written in a XML-document. That's why I need the raw geometric data. As you may know a B-Spline consists of vectors for control points, knots and weights and that's imho a huge difference compared to a straight line.

Comment: That particular problem can be solved by declaring a `printToXML()` method in `GeometricData` that accepts a handle to the XML file to print to. Override that in each subclass, then do the printing by creating an XML file, and simply passing its handle to all your `Edge`s, who in turn pass it to the `printToCML()` method of their `GeometricData` object. Each object appends its own block of text, and voilá!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of solutions.  The one that seems to fit best is [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html); define your `Line` and `Circle` classes as you showed, then make `GeometricData` a typedef of `variant<Line, Circle>`, and you'll be able to store an instance of either one in there.  When you want to go back from a `GeometricData` to the actual object stored, you can [perform a cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/get_idp132758640.html), or you can write a so-called [visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.static-visitor).  A visitor is just a class specifying an action for each possible type, and then [`boost::apply_visitor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html) can be used to select the right action based on what is stored.

Example (using vectors for simpler notation):

```
struct Line {
    Vector3d startPoint, endPoint;
};

struct Circle {
    Vector3d center;
    float radius;
};

using GeometricData = boost::variant<Line, Circle>;

struct MidpointVisitor : boost::static_visitor<Vector3d> const {
    Vector3d operator()(Line const& line) {
        return (line.startPoint + line.endPoint)/2;
    }

    Vector3d operator()(Circle const& circle) const {
        return circle.center;
    }
};

void foo() {
    GeometricData data;
    // ...
    auto midpoint = boost::apply_visitor(MidpointVisitor{}, data);
    // ...
}
```

A less type-strict solution is [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html), but I don't see any advantages for this case.  Even if you did need another option, you'd probably want to specify that explicitly.

I suspect your solution using `void*` (or using a common base class and RTTI) could be made to work using smart pointers.  However, the only advantages I can see are faster compilation and less awful compiler error messages, while you end up having to bother with dynamic allocation and can't have visitors.

You could also roll your own union for this, effectively implementing something along the lines of Variant.  That would involve making sure you get construction, destruction and alignment all correct, and don't trigger some obscure case of undefined behaviour.  If that's not a problem for you and you really don't want to use a library, it's an option, but it is very much reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It sounds pretty much like what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I never worked with boost before and my tutor don't want another library in the project so I have to work with the dynamic allocation

Answer (score 1):

I would say polymorphism where perhaps the shared interface looks something like this:

```
class Edge
{
    enum EdgeType
    {
        CIRCLE,
        LINE
    };

    EdgeType GetType();
}
```

Then in a switch statement somewhere you could do something like:

```
switch (myEdge.GetType())
{
    case Edge::EdgeType::CIRCLE:
        auto myCircle = (Circle)myEdge;
        // do things specific to circle
        break;
    case Edge::EdgeType::LINE:
        auto myLine = (Line)myEdge;
        // do things specific to line
        break;
}
```

That being said, I would try to use polymorphism as much as possible over the switch statement, but the above interface gives you the option of having a function using edges contain the logic for doing different things based on type.

Comment: Note that to avoid slicing of objects during copying `std::vector<Edge>` can't be used. The `vector` must be of some sort of smart pointer or raw pointer, fex `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Edge>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem you're trying solve but from reading and understanding the question, I'd say look into [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c) 
You could maybe create a global array type variable, store the objects you need, serialize it an deserialize it when you need to use it.