# Sending object through named pipe c++

Tags: c++, serialization, named-pipes

I need to transport complex object from one program to another. I have test code which sends simple string:

```
.
.
const wchar_t *data = L"*** Some nice string ***";
        DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
        result = WriteFile(
            pipe, // handle to our outbound pipe
            data, // data to send
            wcslen(data) * sizeof(wchar_t), // length of data to send (bytes)
            &numBytesWritten, // will store actual amount of data sent
            NULL // not using overlapped IO
            );
.
.
```

This is the receiving side:

```
.
.
wchar_t buffer[128];
DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
BOOL result = ReadFile(
pipe,
buffer, // the data from the pipe will be put here
127 * sizeof(wchar_t), // number of bytes allocated
&numBytesRead, // this will store number of bytes actually read
NULL // not using overlapped IO
);
.
.
```

But instead of string I need to send an instance of myIDirect3DDevice9 class, which is basically modified IDirect3DDevice9 class. I suppose serialization is required. What is the most simple and painless way to serialize/send/deserialize c++ object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)