# Serializing a c++ object to be sent over a network

Tags: c++, serialization

I am writing a meeting scheduler program in C++. I am trying to serialize a `Meeting` object over a network. I tried using various serializer libraries online but no luck. How can I approach this problem

```
    class Meeting{
     public:
      int meetingID; //meeting ID
      std::string topic; //topic of the meeting
      std::unordered_set<Person*> attendees; //set of attendees
      Person* host; //host of the meeting
      icaldurationtype* duration; //length of the meeting
      float priority; //priority of the meeting btw 0 - 1
      std::unordered_set<icalperiodtype*> 
      icaltimetype* deadline; //deadline of the meeting
    }
```

Comment: Which serializer libraries have you tried and why did they not succeed?

Comment: I tried "Serializer.h". I think some random person made that up online. I tried "json/json.h", but it only works for my int and string primitives, I tried "ThorsSerializer" which was also made by a random person online too but it kept throwing "no such directory errors", and made me download so many libraries like "yaml" so it got confusing. The boost serialization tutorials on youtube are not helping either. I am new to this, I need help.@PaulRooney

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)

Comment: There is `Boost.Serialization` documentation on the boost [site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), although I acknowledge that such a thing may be intimidating for a beginner, also google protocol buffers. Both of these are mentioned in the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to follow the duplicate question @PaulRooney