# ofstream << operator doesn't write correct size to file

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream

I'm very unsure of file IO when it comes to this, and I'm really confused. When I use the insertion stream operator to push some short integers into the file the size of the file is not what I expect:

```
std::ofstream outFile("myFile.raw", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

std::vector<short> list;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) list.push_back(1);
for (auto i : list) outFile << i;
outFile.close();
```

This creates a file that is 100 bytes big. I'm not understanding, the short is supposed to be two bytes. The documentation shows that the << operator is overloaded for many different types, so I thought that this writes the correct data type. I guess not.

Thanks.

Comment: Use *UnformattedOutputFunction* for binary files, i.e [`std::ofstream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). Also take Endianess into consideration if the binary file is to be used in other platforms

Comment: `<<` prints the number as a string, not its internal representation. So it's just writing `1` every time.

Comment: Isn't that what you see if you do `cout << i;`? Don't you expect the file to contain the same thing?

Comment: use `outFile.write(&i, 2);`

Comment: @Barmar Ummm, well no, I didn't, truth is I have no idea. I thought setting the ios::binary flag would have done something like that. I mean made it unformatted as opposed to working with strings.

Comment: @Titone The binary flag simply says how things like line-ending characters are to be treated; it doesn't magically turn the stream into binary.

Comment: @latedeveloper that is what "turn the stream into binary" means

Comment: @M.M  By turning it into binary I meant (for example) writing out each int as (on a 32-bit system) 4 bytes.

Comment: What does the internal file format in which a `short` happens to be stored on your platform have to do with any file format?

Answer (score 4):

You are using [formatted output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction).

The `short int`s are written as digits. Each digit is `1` which is a single `char` of a single byte.

So the total is 100. If you had `short int`s containing double digit numbers, say `22`, then the size would be 200.

---

As an alternative you could either use [unformatted output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedOutputFunction) or you could cast the data to `char`s, which together with the `binary` flag you have set will write the data without formatting it. Something to keep in mind when writing raw `char`s is that you will have to consider how many bytes and [how you want to order the bytes](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) in the file.

---

Formatted output and input could be more convenient in general. As an alternative to writing the file with raw `char`s it would be better to look into [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234740/1460794).

Comment: Thank you. I thought setting the ios::binary flag would have made it work. I'm really clueless about this.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice If you think about it, that would mean that `operator<<` would have to interrogate the stream mode and produce completely different output (in one case a number, in another case a native representation of a number) based on that mode. That really would be an illogical design.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is - as mentioned in the comments an in the previous answer - that operator `<<` is formatted output and writes value `1` as a single digit (which consists of only one character).

Just for the sake of showing how a short int could be written as binary, see the following code:

```
std::ofstream outFile("myFile.raw", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

std::vector<short> list;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) list.push_back(1);
for (auto i : list) outFile.write((const char*)&i, sizeof(i));
outFile.close();

std::ifstream in("myFile.raw", std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
std::cout << "File size: " <<  in.tellg() << std::endl;
// prints out: File size: 200
in.close();
```

Comment: And no need to change `auto` back to `short int` in the range-for loop. `auto` will work just fine.

Comment: I thought sizeof i was a typo because it was missing the parentheses.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice the syntax is `sizeof expression` or `sizeof(type name)`. Expressions can be parenthesized but don't have to be