# How to serialize generic object without using external libraries (C++ 11)

Tags: c++11, serialization

I tried to find with no success how to serialize a generic object. Every solution that was suggested knew the type/ used some external library (i.e boost/cereal).
I have a `template` and in it I need to update a file.
The file needs to hold `unordered_map<std::string, T>`.
Is there a way to serialize an object `T` without knowing it's type/it's members **without** using an external library?

Comment: There is no inbuilt way, no. You'd have to write your own serialization library (which is probably not a good use of your time compared to using an external one).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)