# send pcl point cloud over tcp in c++

Tags: c++, tcp, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am new to data serialization in c++, I searched for examples but I was not really successful.
My goal is to be able to send and receive a pcl point cloud over tcp in c++. I am familiar with ROS, but now I cannot use it in the server. I have to send point cloud through ethernet to a client machine, where I am free to use ROS.

I tried Python with ZeroMQ configured to send the point cloud in numpy array. The message contained a json markdown with the array shape and then another message contained the array.
If i am correct, in c++ I should serialize my `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud` object to be able to send it somehow. In case of c++ I cannot find it possible to send array shape as markdown.
Is it possible in c++ to send this *cloud* object similar as in zmq? Or is there a more handy approach to this problem?

***update:***
In cpp, I read the point cloud from camera, into `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` object. My goal is to send *somehow* this data through tcp and be able to reconstruct into a similar point cloud object preferably in cpp.

Comment: What should the serialized data look like? Can you update your answer with an example of the Python/C++ datatypes and the serialized data?

Comment: Yes, i updated. I should encode pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> before sending with zmq, and be able to decode into the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not provide a standard method to serialize and deserialize data.

You can implement this yourself for simple cases.

For more complex cases you can use a library, such as [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) or [Boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

You can also use a text-based format "on the wire", such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I also looked around and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234740) helpful answer about serialization. In my case I cannot modify the pcd structure so if I am right, I have to use your mentioned boost or protobuf library?As I inspect pcd, there are `operator<<` defined. Does it really make easier this serialization [in this form](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/common_2include_2pcl_2point__cloud_8h_source.html) or do I need to write a serialization/deserialization from scratch, related to pcl data structure?

Another q: If i use zmq in c++, do I still need to serialize?

Comment: You do not need to modify any existing structure. You can create functions to write data from the object to a stream and to read data from a stream and re-create the object. ZeroMQ does not provide serialization.